# PHP single quotes vs double quotes

Tags: php, quotes

I am wondering the difference between the single quotes:

```
$this->db->select('card_code, card_color');
```

Versus the double quotes:

```
$this->db->select("card_code, card_color");
```

I know if I use double quotes I can place variables in the string, like so:

```
$this->db->select("$card_code_var, $card_color_var");
```

While with single quotes this does not work.
And also when using it in in english or other spoken languages there can be occasions where I need to use apostrophe like here

```
$this->setPhrase("The cat's tail is black");
```

And up to here I get it.

I see on the web many official guides and documentation where they use single quotes for strings.
Shouldn't be single quotes used for **single characters** and double quotes for **strings**?

```
$var_char = 'A';
$var_string = "A fox";
```

Does programmatically change something if I use a single quotes (like in the very first code above) rather than double quotes?

Comment: http://php.net/types.string
Single quotes are faster than double quotes because If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters

Comment: "Shouldn't be single quotes used for single characters and double quotes for strings?" No. This isn't C++. PHP uses both types of quotes for strings.

Comment: I found it a practical thing to go by this rule of thumb, unless you have situations where contained quote chars dictate otherwise: for human readable strings (so text phrases, stuff to be translated) I use double quotes, for technical identifiers I use single quotes.

Comment: @Mr.Web have you even tried figuring this out on your own before asking? You've been around for almost 3 years. You should know better. I'm even wondering why you don't have any down votes.

Comment: Tku guys. @mrun I don't see how your comment may be helpful and your question is rhetorical. If I had figured it out I would not even asked the question. Further I don't see how "time" and "years in the field" are the solution to a question. I don't "know better", the first barrier to learn something is thinking you already know everything about it. I do know a lot of stuff, but I feel I'll never stop learning, even little details do make the difference, this is the reason for my question. If is a matter of "double question" than I apologise.

Comment: I meant you should know better when  to ask questions on SO. It's clear that you haven't done any research whatsoever before posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One useful additional fact I may mention is **speed** - in case of double quotes `""` PHP will search every string for variables. This really is not an issue in general day to day programming, but if you have a specific large script where performance really matters, optimizing it may pay off a bit.

Comment: According to this comment, at least, single quotes aren't necessarily always faster. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#120160